# DNS Level Load Balancing

Tags: load-balancing, dns-hosting, traffic-management

Is it possible in this world to achieve DNS Level Load Balancing? For example, I have a Server A (111.222.333.444) and Server B (555.666.777.888), and there be some third party DNS hosting (like CloudFlare) which could decide if Server A is down (or not responding) then divert all traffic to Server B. This is not a true load balancing, rather a traffic diversion, I don't know. But is it possible?

I know DNS propagation takes time, but services like CloudFlare barely take a few minutes to divert to other server.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DNS can very well be used for *load balancing*, but it's only able to do things like simple round robin.

If you want to implement something like a *high availability* solution in DNS, you'll have to disable IPs that are unavailable, for which you would need to set the TTL to some minimum value, which is not a good idea.

In general its a much better idea to use solutions like [Heartbeat](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Main_Page).

With Heartbeat, the scenario would look like the following:

You have Server A and Server B. Heartbeat is checking continuously if Server A and B are OK. If Heartbeat detects that Server A has a problem, it simply assigns Server A's IP to Server B. So then Server B is serving the requests for both IPs.

That way, for the user, there is only a minimal service interruption of a second or two that heartbeat takes to reassign the IPs and propagate the updated ARP. That is much faster than you could ever propagate a DNS change.